# How to connect, create database, reconnect with that database and create tables in knex.js?

Tags: node.js, promise, knex.js

I am working with knex.js. I have kind of a weird set up going on. I can't be sure that the MySQL database I'm connecting to has my database already set up.

So, first I connect without specifying a database. Then, I create a database and reconnect to with that specified database. After that, I want to create three different tables. But I keep getting a `Error: ER_BAD_DB_ERROR: Unknown database '<dbname>'`. I have this code,

```
    knex.raw('CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ' + database + ';'
    ).then(function() {
        knex.destroy();
        knexConnect.connection.database = database;
        knex = require('knex')(knexConnect);
    }).then(function() {
        knex.schema.createTable('items', initializeItems
        ).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
          });

        knex.schema.createTable('lessons', initializeLessons
        ).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
          });

        knex.schema.createTable('reviews', initializeReview
        ).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    });
```

What would I need to change in order to get the table creation commands to be executed after the reconnection has been established and the database created?

Comment: Does `require('knex')(knexConnect);` return a promise?

Comment: I dont think so. It didn't let me attach a `.then(...)` to `require('knex')(knexConnect)`.